# Free shipping issue and Country Shipping Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shipping-address, free-shipping

I have an issue with Free shipping. I set up free shipping over 29 euro only for orders coming from Italy. Following issue:

If I change the amount to reach to get free shipping, let’s say Free shipping over 19 euro or I remove the special offer, changes it doesn’t get effected; you can keep having free shipping over 29 euro.

I set up Free shipping for all orders coming from Italy but it seems that it also applied to other countries. I've selected Italy in countries list.

I've setup countries to which we deliver, but the cart is allowing all countries.

check the screen shot. I set up everything correct just like you suggested but it still doesn't work out.

What should i do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting Up Free Shipping

Free shipping is one of the most effective promotions you can offer. It can be based on a minimum purchase, or set up as a shopping cart price rule that applies when a set of conditions has been met. If both apply to the same order, the configuration setting will take precedence over the shopping cart rule.

> See your shipping carrier configuration for any additional settings
>   that may be required for free shipping.

[image]

Free Shipping In Shopping Cart

To set up free shipping:

On the Admin menu, select **System > Configuration**.

In the Configuration panel on the left, under Sales, select **Shipping Methods**.

Click to expand the **Free Shipping** section. Then, do the following:
Set **Enabled** to “Yes.”

Enter the **Title** for this shipping method that you want to appear during checkout.
Enter a descriptive **Method Name** to internally identify this shipping method.
Enter the **Minimum Order Amount** to qualify an order for free shipping.

To use Free Shipping with [Table Rates](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/setting-up-table-rate-shipping/), you must enter a Minimum Order Amount so high that it is never met. This prevents Free Shipping from going into effect, unless triggered by a price rule.

In the **Displayed Error Message** box, type the message to appear if this method becomes unavailable.
Set **Ship to Applicable Countries** to one of the following:
All Allowed CountriesCustomers from all countries specified in your store configuration can use this shipping method.
Specific CountriesAfter choosing this option, the Ship to Specific Countries list appears. Select each country in the list where this shipping method can be used. (To select multiple options, hold the Ctrl (PC) or Command (Mac) key down, and click each option.)


Set **Show Method if Not Applicable** to one of the following:
YesAlways shows the Free Shipping method, even when not applicable.
NoShows the Free Shipping method only when applicable.


Enter a **Sort Order** number to determine the position of  Free Shipping in the list of shipping methods during checkout. (0 = first, 1 = second, 2 = third, and so on.)

[image]

Make sure that you complete any configuration settings that are required for each
carrier you plan to use with free shipping. For example, assuming that your UPS configuration is otherwise
complete, make the following settings to enable and configure free shipping:
From the Shipping Methods configuration, click to expand the **UPS** section.

In the UPS section, set **Free Method** to “Ground.”
To require a minimum order for free shipping, set **Free Shipping with Minimum Order Amount** to “Enable.”
Enter the required amount in the **Minimum Order Amount for Free Shipping** field.

When complete, click the **Save Config** button.